# Sending E-Mail through app causes it to crash

Tags: c#, email, windows-phone-8.1

I am using `ShowComposeNewEmailAsync()`.

```
        EmailRecipient sendTo = new EmailRecipient()
            {
                Address = "example@example.com"
            };
        //generate mail object
        EmailMessage mail = new EmailMessage();
        mail.Subject = subject.Text;
        mail.Body = body.Text;

        //add recipients to the mail object
        mail.To.Add(sendTo);

        //open the share contract with Mail only:
        await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(mail);
```

The app crashes in phone when I have more than 1 app(I had multiple Google Mail Account IDs logged in in email+accounts i.e. Google Mail,Google Mail 2,Google Mail 3) to do this or have no email set in email+accounts in Settings.

When I call this function and have more than 1 account, the app selector appears for 2 or 3 seconds (showing Google Mail,Google Mail 2,Google Mail 3 in the list)  and then disappears before I can select anything closing the app along with it.

If no accounts are available then a message appears saying no apps are installed to share for 1-2 seconds and then it disappears closing the app along with it.

How to prevent this from happening?

Comment: you should provide a small, yet complete reproduce of your problem. Otherwise, it would be *really* hard to guess what you're doing.

Comment: Can you provide *any* information about the "crash"?  It's really hard to follow what you're talking about, especially with such descriptions as "My app crashed in phone when I [...] have no app".

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem, the list of accounts is there for a few seconds, then crashes along with the app, no exception is caught

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with simple values? This works fine for me, and I have several e-mail accounts on my phone:

```
var msg = new EmailMessage();
msg.Subject = "Hello this is a test";
msg.Body = "Testing 123";
msg.To.Add(new EmailRecipient("address@somewhere.com"));
await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(msg);
```

Do you have your code wrapped in a `try`/`catch` in case you are getting an exception that is being lost during the async call?

Comment: No, I don't have a try/catch. I am doing this in a ContentDialog if that somehow matters.

Comment: That works fine for me also. The `ContentDialog` is dismissed when you navigate away, so maybe there is some code running at that time that is crashing? For example, if you `await dialog.ShowAsync()` then whatever comes next will try and execute while the app is in the background, which typically doesn't end well.